# convert stationary model to dynamic model

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-integration, odeint

I am trying to simulate the flow of a reservoir in Python using the following equations:
[image: Pressure equation]

[image: Darcy Equation]

[image: Density equation]

```
def dRho(rho_y, t):
    P_r = 10e5
    rho_r = 900
    L = 750
    H = 10
    W = 150
    A = H * W
    V = A * L
    fi = 0.17

    k = 1.2e-13
    c = 12.8e-9
    mu = 2e-3

    N = 1
    dV = V/N
    dx = L/N

    P_in = P_r
    rho_in = rho_r

    P_w = 1e5
    rho_w = rho_r* np.exp(c*(P_w-P_r))

    P = P_r + (1/c) * np.log(rho_y/rho_r)
    dP_in = P - P_in
    dP_uit = P_w - P

    Q_in = (-A*k/mu)*(dP_in/dx)
    Q_uit = (-A*k/mu)*(dP_uit/dx)
    return (Q_in*rho_in - Q_uit*rho_y)/dV

t0 = np.linspace(0,1e9, 1e9/100)
rho0 = 900
solve = odeint(dRho, rho0, t0)
plt.plot(t0,solve, '-')
plt.show()
```

So far I am able to solve the stationary form of the equations using:
I have tried to convert the stationary script to a dynamic version using numpy arrays and slicing but I didn't get anywhere close to solving the equations dynamically. I mainly have trouble using/implementing values using the variables with a subscript (i.e. i, i+1 and i-1).

My try of applying the dynamic equations:

```
def dRho(rho_y, t):
    # reservoir 
    P_r = 10e5
    rho_r = 900
    L = 750
    H = 10
    W = 150
    A = H * W
    V = A * L
    fi = 0.17
    # fluid 
    k = 1.2e-13
    c = 12.8e-9
    mu = 2e-3
    # components
    N = 10
    dV = V/N
    dx = L/N

    # inlet
    P_in = P_r
    rho_in = rho_r
    # outlet
    P_w = 1e5    
    rho_w = rho_r* np.exp(c*(P_w-P_r))


    rhoi = rho_y[1:-1] # i
    rhop = rho_y[2:]   # i + 1
    rhom = rho_y[:-2]  # i - 1

    # compressibility
    Pi = P_r + (1/c) * np.log(rhoi/rho_r)  # i
    Pm = P_r + (1/c) * np.log(rhom/rho_r) #i - 1

    # Darcy
    Qi = (-A*k/mu)*((Pi)/dx) # i
    Qp = (-A*k/mu)*((Pm-Pi)/dx) # i + 1

    return (Qp*rhop - Qi*rhoi)/dV

t0 = np.linspace(0,1e9, 1e9/100)
rho0 = np.ones(10)*900
solve = odeint(dRho, rho0, t0)
plt.plot(t0,solve, '-', label='dRho')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

Edit 1:
I have added some more initial values that were missing in the script. My new code is:

```
def dRho(rho_y, t):
    # reservoir 
    P_r = 10e5
    rho_r = 900
    L = 750
    H = 10
    W = 150
    A = H * W
    V = A * L
    fi = 0.17
    # fluid 
    k = 1.2e-13
    c = 12.8e-9
    mu = 2e-3
    # components
    N = 8
    dV = V/N
    dx = L/N

    # inlet
    P_in = P_r
    rho_in = rho_r
    # outlet
    P_w = 1e5    
    rho_w = rho_r* np.exp(c*(P_w-P_r))


    rhoi = rho_y[1:-1] # i
    rhop = rho_y[2:]   # i + 1
    rhom = rho_y[:-2]  # i - 1

    # compressibility
    Pi = P_r + (1/c) * np.log(rhoi/rho_r) # i
    Pm = P_r + (1/c) * np.log(rhom/rho_r) #i - 1

    # Darcy
    Q0 = 0
    Qi = (-A*k/mu)*((Pi)/dx) # i
    Qp = (-A*k/mu)*((Pm-Pi)/dx) # i + 1

    out = np.empty(N+1)
    out[0] = 0
    out[1:N] = (Qp*rhop - Qi*rhoi)/dV
    out[N] = 0
    return out

t0 = np.linspace(0,1e9, 1e9/200)
N = 8
rho0 = np.ones(N+1)*900
solve = odeint(dRho, rho0, t0)
plt.plot(t0,solve, '-', label='dRho')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

Unfortunately, the output from this script is not exactly what I am looking for and honestly I don't see my mistake.

Current output:
[image: Current output]

While the desired output should look more like this:
[image: Desired output]

I achieved the desired output by hardcoding P_i, Q_i and dRho/dt for i=8.

Edit 2:

I have achieved the desired output by creating a series of 3 for-loops, one for each of the aforementioned equations. However, my script takes quite some time to execute since the big O nation = n^3

Here is my code:

```
def dRho(rho_y, t, N):
    # reservoir 
    P_r = 10e5
    rho_r = 900
    L = 750
    H = 10
    W = 150
    A = H * W
    V = A * L
    fi = 0.17
    # fluid 
    k = 1.2e-13
    c = 12.8e-9
    mu = 2e-3
    # components
    N = N
    dV = V/N
    dx = L/N

    # inlet
    P_in = P_r
    rho_in = rho_r
    # outlet
    P_w = 1e5    
    rho_w = rho_r* np.exp(c*(P_w-P_r))

    P = np.empty(N+1)*10e5
    Q = np.ones(N+1)
    out = np.empty(N+1)

    P[0] = P_w
    for i in range(1,N):
        P[i] = P_r + (1/c) * np.log(rho_y[i]/rho_r)

    P[N] = P_r + (1/c) * np.log(rho_y[N]/rho_r)

    Q[0] = 0
    for i in range(1,N):
        Q[i] = (-A*k/mu)*((P[i-1] - P[i])/dx)
    Q[N] = (-A*k/mu)*((P[N]-P_r)/dx)

    out[0] = 0
    for i in range(1,N):
        out[i] = ((Q[i+1]*rho_y[i+1] - Q[i]*rho_y[i])/dV) 
    out[N] = 0

    return out

t0 = np.linspace(0,1e9, int(1e9/200))
N = 100
rho0 = np.ones(N+1)*900
solve = odeint(dRho, rho0, t0, args=(N,))
print(solve[:,0])


rho_i = np.ones(len(t0))*900
plt.plot(t0,solve[:,1:len(rho0)-1], '-', label='dRho')
plt.plot(t0,rho_i, '-', label='dRho_initial')
# plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

Is there a way to still automate this while executing in a reasonable time.

Comment: have you had a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032396/solving-dynamic-number-of-non-linear-equations-in-python Or this one: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html#scipy.optimize.fsolve

Comment: The problem here is extremely close to the one you asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46223725/implement-an-integration-math-equation-using-odeint-in-python 
Can you state how it is different? The numerical values were off in the other post but the solution is the same. The problem misses a boundary condition anyway: Q_0 and Q_1 do not have a value here, as `d rho_i / dt` for i=N.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl In this case I have Q_i+1 * rho_i+1 - Q_i * rho_i. In the previous case I was simply able to create one array that calculated deltaY for me. I am trying to understand the logical implementation dRho/dt while Q_i+1, Q_i, rho_i+1 and rho_i are calculated as we go. I have added the boundary conditions to the initial post but unfortunately I don't get the right output

Comment: `Q_{i+1}` depends on `P_{i-1}`. So, the value of `Q_1` and `Q_0` need to be specified by a boundary condition. What is it? Formulated as equations, I mean.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl I see that I added the equation for Q_{i+1} this is supposed to be Q_i. I have updated this initial post with the correct formula. Also, I am interested in the values for N>1 so even in my hardcoded version Q_0 is never used. However, I might be wrong about not needing Q_0. Furthermore since I am looking for values meeting N>1 dRho/dt[0] = 0

Comment: @PierredeBuyl I have achieved the desired result by converting the hardcoded version to a series of 3 for-loops. However, as states n the initial post it takes quite some time to execute. Last time you suggested using arrays, can I apply that here and still receive the correct output under a reasonable amount of time?

Comment: I have figured it out, the integration with odeint takes a few seconds while creating a plot and showing it takes a few minutes.